# Global variable from a newly loaded script is not accessible within eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Here is my html file that loads two scripts.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="textscript">
            <script id="text" type="text/javascript" src=".scripts/script1.js"></script>
        <div>
        <div id="indexscript">
            <script id="scr" type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
        <div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Scripts are as follows:

**script1.js**

```
var x=1
```

**script2.js**

```
var x=2
```

**index.js**

```
var e = document.getElementById("content")
e.textContent=x

function update(e){
 replaceScript()
}



document.addEventListener('keypress',update)

function replaceScript(){
    document.getElementById("text").remove()
    var s = document.createElement("script")
    s.setAttribute("id","text")
    s.setAttribute("src","./scripts/script2.js")
    s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    document.getElementById("textscript").appendChild(s)
    var c= document.getElementById("content")
    c.textContent=x
}
```

On key press, the expected behavior is that, script1 must be removed and script2 must be added. As a result value of x must be 2 and consequently *textContent* of div with id="content" must be 2. But it remains that x=1 on first key press. Only on second key press x gets updated to 2.

Can anyone please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is actually loaded after execution of your function finish. You can listen `load` event on the script element.

```
s.addEventListener('load', () => console.log(x));
```